# Return Text from StatefulBuilder by Timer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, timer

I want to make a widget that returns text by timer without rebuilding all elements at page, how to make my widget return Text with countdownNumber value?

```
  Widget CDtimer(){

    return StatefulBuilder(
     builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {

       var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
       sub.onData((duration) {

         setState(() {
           currentNumber += stepInSeconds;

           countdownNumber = timeOutInSeconds - currentNumber;

           countdownNumber += stepInSeconds;
         }
         );

       });

       sub.onDone(() {
         sub.cancel();
       });
     }
        );
    }
```